# How and where to deploy an Angular 8 web application that needs two servers concurrently [MEAN stack]

Tags: angular, deployment, web-deployment

I have a web application. It's a blog and question-answer website made with MEAN stack making CRUD operations using `Mongodb`. Before this I have deployed many applications built in `react` and `angular` wherein only one server was required i.e. `npm start` as there was no back-end `server` code. But this time I decided to keep my back-end code separate from my front-end code. `server.js` is in a different folder and is running on `port:3000`, while application is running on `localhost:4200`. I am using `cors` for cross origin communication. The project is open source. I have uploaded on github. Here's the [repo](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder). Consider it all yours. Please at least give me some hint how to deploy this project. I'm ready to buy domain and `VPS` also.

PS: Please go through [README.md](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: after building the angular application , you can place the build files (which is normal html and js file) in any of the server like for example  Apache

Answer (score 1):

for production build of the angular application you have to use **ng build --prod** 
with these command you will get the compiled version of your application inside the dist folder 
serve this dist folder using nodejs

```
var express = require("express");
var compression = require('compression')

var port = 7600;

var app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/dist', { etag: true, maxAge: '3d' }));

app.get('*', function (req,res) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname + '/dist' })
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
})
```

you can use nodejs to create server or expressjs just your port number should be different than your backend server

Comment: I followed the instructions but I'm getting MIME errors on browser console. Please help.

Comment: have you made  a file named server.js or app.js and run it on the localmachine and then try to run it on server

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to use `ng build --prod` for compile your development file.
2. Then you need to setup your node.js file. 
   [please check the code](https://github.com/souravgolui/matDash/blob/master/server.js)
3. Then just upload all the server files and dist folder to server.
4. And run the server using `pm2` . You have to install it from [please check this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)
5. And run just `pm2 start server.js`

That's it. Now your `fron-end` and `back-end` run together on your specific `port`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually I want to deploy it on Heroku or GoDaddy, etc.

Comment: Done. Everything looks good. It is up and running. But i dont know on which port my application is running.

Comment: please check  `app.listen()`. you defined the port like 3000, 2000, 8080.

Comment: Getting this error:
`Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

Comment: Sir you've to help me in this. Still not working. I'm getting some MIME types. Created a new question but there are no good answers. Please help.