# Node.js Server calling HTML calling Javascript Module: Disallowed MIME Type and/or "require" not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using the Spotify API to make an app for a school project, but I'm having trouble on the front-end of the project. The idea is a Node.JS server is running an HTML file, which will call on a java script module which is attempting to import the Spotify API.

**simpapp.js :** Run in node.js command prompt with node simpapp.js

```
var path = require("path");
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var fs = require('fs');
var cors = require('cors');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'simpbutton.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
                res.writeHeader(404, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                })
                res.write('404 Not Found');
                res.end();
                return;
            }

            if (req.url.endsWith('.html')) {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                });
            }

            if (req.url.endsWith('.js')) {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
                });
            }

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});

console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);
```

**simpbutton.html :** called on by simpapp.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <tile>Testing MIME Type Imports</tile>
    <script type="module" src="/js/throwaway.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="basicAlert()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

**throwaway.js :** called on by simpbutton.html

```
//Produces Error "Loading module from “http://localhost:8888/js/spotify-web-api-js” 
//was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)."
import Spotify from "./spotify-web-api-js";

//Produces Error "ReferenceError: require is not defined"
//var Spotify = require("spotify-web-api-js");
// ^ I only will have one active at a time while the other is commented

function basicAlert() {
    alert("this is a test to see if basicAlert runs properly");
}

console.log("Should print to console with no error on imports");
```

And spotify-web-api-js can be found here: https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js
Both my errors are seen in console when running the server (details seen in throwaway.js).

I have already seen [Node server: Loading module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088076/node-server-loading-module-was-blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-text) which is extremely similar, but its answer did not solve my problem.

Any assistance to get either of these import methods work would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: In case it's wondered, the file structure is not the issue; that has been tested with a "text/javascript" script in HTML without the imports and it works perfectly then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new **throwaway.js**:

```
import * as Spotify from "./spotify-web-api.js";

window.basicAlert = function basicAlert() {
    alert("this is a test to see if basicAlert runs properly");
}

console.log("Should print to console with no error on imports");
```

importing the file as `* as Spotify` enables the import and avoiding the MIME type error while window.basicAlert will submit my basicAlert function to the file that imports it (otherwise basicAlert is not defined).

I'm surprised no one else answered on the `import * as Spotify from` cause it seems like such a simple error.