# How to send headers in Express [MEAN]

Tags: javascript, deployment, mean-stack, mime-types

I'm a beginner in Express. So I might've failed to frame the question properly. I have created a MEAN application wherein I've separated my `frontend` and `backened`. Frontend runs on `port:4200` and server runs on `port:3000`. I wanted to run both frontend and backend on same port as part of deployment. I'm getting MIME type errors, someone told me that there is some problem with my server environment. Maybe I'm not sending headers properly. Here is my code:
I have mentioned tried solutions in the code itself as `<----TRIED THIS`

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
express.static.mime.define({'application/javascript': ['js']}); <----TRIED THIS

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

// express.static.mime.define({'application/javascript': ['js']}); <----TRIED THIS

const api = require('./routes/api');

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  // res.send('Hello from the server'); <----TRIED THIS
  // res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); <----TRIED THIS
  // res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); <----TRIED THIS
  // res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json"); <----TRIED THIS

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/application/index.html'));
})
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server listening on PORT '+PORT);
});
```

**api.js**
For instance I'm showing you GET function only

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = <my db string>;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

mongoose.connect(
 ...
)

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
 ...
}

router.get('/myarticles', (req, res) => {
  var person="Tanzeel Mirza";
  console.log('Get request for tanzeel articles');
  Article.find({contributor: person}, (error, article) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    else {
      if(!article) {
        res.status(401).send('Invalid email')
      }
      else if(2>4) {
        console.log("test passed");
      }
      else {
        res.json(article);
      }
    }
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

But still I'm getting

> Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/runtime-xxx.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
>
> Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/polyfills-xxx.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
>
> Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/main-xxx.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

Please correct me.

PS: I asked separate questions for MIME error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173204/module-was-blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-text-html). But no answers.

Comment: Are the JavaScript files held in the static folder `path.join(__dirname, 'dist')` ? If so, log the value returned from `path.join` and check if it is correct. If not, which middleware call  is supposed handle  serving script files?

Comment: @Tanzeel. Static middleware should handle the mime types on itself.  Please have a look at the repl https://repl.it/repls/SoreFearlessNagware. I made some minor  edits and  it seems to work for me

Comment: @nithin. thank you sir. this worked with a minor change in path. Sir can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. Really thankful to you sir

Comment: @nithin can you confirm that you are **not** requesting the js file preceded by `dist/` in the URL? That would return a 404 http status message _of mimetype text/html_ and could also explain the problem!

Comment: @traktor53 No {dist/} in URL

Comment: @Tanzeel Let me know if you are following the same steps as in my answer. Update your code accordingly as in my sample code posted in REPL. Posting as anwer as your other question didn't get an answer for 5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your assets are inside dist/application folder, Use  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/application')));`

To match all web app routes, Use `app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/application/index.html'));
})`.

This a generic route and  will be called into action only if express can't find any other routes and always serve index.html. For example any valid `/api` route will never reach this handler, as there a specific route that handles it.

**Final code for server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');


const api = require('./routes/api');

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/application')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/application/index.html'));
})

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server listening on PORT '+PORT);
});
```

A few points to not.

To serve static files, you need not set any headers manually. Express looks up the files in the folder (`dist` folder in your case)  you set as static directory with the `express.static` middleware function. Express also sets the response headers based on the file extension.

So you don't need `express.static.mime.define` in your code anymore.

In your case you have defined `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));` which listens for static files at `dist` folder. In this `app.use` command, you haven't used a mount path which means that all the requests will go through the static middleware. If the middleware finds an asset with the same name, path and extension in dist folder it returns the file, else the request is passed to the other route handlers.

Also, If you are using static middleware, as long as there is an index.html in dist folder (immediate child of dist folder), your route handler for "/" will never get invoked as the response will be served by the middleware.

If you don't have an index html file in dist folder(immediate child of dist), but it's present somewhere in subfolders of dist, and still you need to access it using root path "/", only then you need a route handler for path "/" as below.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/application/index.html"));
});
```

JS files referred using `"./"` in `dist/application/index.html` are referred relative to dist folder itself and **NOT** `dist/application` folder.

You can refer this REPL for updated code .
https://repl.it/repls/SoreFearlessNagware

Try below urls

`/api/myarticles` - Rendered by "/api" route handler

`/api/myarticles.js` - Rendered by static asset middleware because the file exists in dist/api folder

`/` -  rendered using "/" route handler and res.sendFile because index.html doesn't exist in dist folder.

`/test.js` - Rendered using static middleware because file exists in dist folder

**Additional links for reference.**

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Unfortunately the updated code has landed me into the same old problem. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978442/getting-mime-type-errors-with-mean-stack-project-while-deploying-it.  Its been 18 days and still no answer.

Comment: @Tanzeel After I generated your assets. Used the github link provided in the other question. Im able to load the Application. With only one change
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/application')));  All the assets are inside the application folder. So express static middleware should point there.

Comment: Yes sir. I did the same. Worked for me. But try to refresh the page. Then you'll encounter the problem. I mean. Click some button on navbar and then hit refresh button on the browser.

Comment: Here is the entire project on github https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder. Before `ng build --prod`. Please clne it.

Comment: Change app.get('/', function(req, res) {}) to app.get("*", function(req, res) {}). And restart

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank a lot Sir. But how. A quick explanation plz?

Comment: app.get("/") will respond with index.html only for root url. app.get("*") with respond with index.html for all paths. JS will handle rendering the content.  I will update the answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Tanzeel You are welcome. Please mark this as right answer/ upvote if found helpful and link other unanswered stories to here. Good day :)

Answer (score 1):

1.Build your angular project, either inside or outside the server folder using `ng build` cmd.

2.To build your project inside server, change the `dist`-folder path in `angular-cli`.

3.To change path, either use cli cmd or edit the `angular-cli.json` file's `"outDir": "./location/toYour/dist"`
Or by using this cli cmd `ng build --output-path=dist/example/`

4.Then In your server root file include the static `build/dist` folder using express.

5.Like this `app.use(express.static(path.join( 'your path to static folder')));`

6.Now **restart** your server.